# Get distinct values in union all in hive

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, union-all

I have a table in hive that looks something like this

```
cust_id  prod_id timestamp
1        11      2011-01-01 03:30:23
2        22      2011-01-01 03:34:53
1        22      2011-01-01 04:21:03
2        33      2011-01-01 04:44:09
3        33      2011-01-01 04:54:49
```

so on and so forth.

For each record I want to check that how many unique products has this customer bought within the last 24 hrs excluding the current transaction. So the output should look something like this -

```
1     0
2     0
1     1
2     1
3     0
```

My hive query looks something like this

```
select * from(
select t1.cust_id, count(distinct t1.prod_id) as freq from temp_table t1
left outer join temp_table t2 on (t1.cust_id=t2.cust_id) 
where t1.timestamp>=t2.timestamp 
and unix_timestamp(t1.timestamp)-unix_timestamp(t2.timestamp) < 24*60*60
group by t1.cust_id
union all
select t.cust_id, 0 as freq from temp_table t2
)unioned;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "excluding the current transaction"? Do you mean "the latest transaction"?

Answer (score 0):

Just get all the rows for last 24 hours do a group by on custid and count(distinct productid) -1 as the output. Overall query would look something like this.

> select cust_id, COUNT(distinct prod_id) - 1 from table_name where
>   unix_timestamp(t1.timestamp)-unix_timestamp(t2.timestamp) < 24*60*60
>   GROUP BY cust_id

*I am subtracting 1 here to exclude the latest transactionid of the user. (hope this is what you meant)

Answer (score 0):

You can join to a derived table that contains the distinct # of products purchased in the past 24 hours for each customer/timestamp pair.

```
select t1.cust_id, t1.prod_id, t1.timestamp, t2.count_distinct_prod_id - 1
from mytable t1
join (
    select t2.cust_id, t2.timestamp, count(distinct t3.prod_id) count_distinct_prod_id
    from mytable t2
    join mytable t3 on t3.cust_id = t2.cust_id
    where unix_timestamp(t2.timestamp) - unix_timestamp(t3.timestamp) < 24*60*60
    group by t2.cust_id, t2.timestamp
) t2 on t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id and t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp
```